# How to host an offline snap store

Tags: snap

I need to host a local snap store where we can host our offline repositories for reproducible system installs. We already mirror the apt repositories with versioned snapshots so we control the upgrade process, but cannot find any documentation on hosting a store for the snaps.

I only found [this guide](https://ubuntu.com/blog/howto-host-your-own-snap-store) so I know that I can point snapd to a custom store by setting the `SNAPPY_FORCE_CPI_URL` environment variable.

Unfortunately the [snapstore project](https://github.com/noise/snapstore) which this guide points to "is not compatible with the current snapd implementation. As a result I have removed the contents here to avoid further confusion.".

Is there any guide on how to host snaps so the commands to install them can find them without any changes.

Comment: I was going to suggest checking out an article about making a Steam cache, but apparently it's deprecated and the team now works on [LanCache](http://lancache.net). It looks like a more generalized version of the original even though the main concentration is still as a game install data cache with their project [Monolithic](https://github.com/lancachenet/monolithic). They do list Windows Update as something they can cache, and apt on Ubuntu 19+ [probably still uses http by default](https://github.com/lancachenet/monolithic), but I'm stuck on Ubuntu 18 via Android, so can't verify personally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canonical has two commercial products which might help:

- You can use a [Brand Store](https://ubuntu.com/internet-of-things/appstore) to host private snaps and/or self-host a Snap store.
- You can use the [Snap Store Proxy](https://snapcraft.io/snap-store-proxy) to have snaps from the regular Snap Store available in an offline environment.

I know the Snap Store Proxy has a free tier, but I don't know if Brand Stores have one.

Comment: This looks great. The offline mode is currently a beta, but we can work with Canonical on this. https://docs.ubuntu.com/snap-store-proxy/en/airgap

Comment: Current Brand Store pricing for just the IoT App Store *starts* at $5000.  There is no free tier.

Comment: @ThomasWard-OnStrike afaik, the app store starts at $15.000/y. The $5.000 option is for _training_ on how to deploy and use the brand store.

FYI: if you're looking for an open source alternative, please contact me privately. I might have something to show soon.

Comment: Doesn't seem to say *training only* but technically there's nobody stopping on-prem airgapped with the training AFAICT?

Answer (score 0):

Besides from Canonical's commercial products, hosting your own snap store seems to be quite easy judging from this blog post:

https://ubuntu.com/blog/howto-host-your-own-snap-store

Comment: The blog post refers to https://github.com/noise/snapstore as an example, but the readme currently says `snapstore was a minimalist example of a "store" for snaps, but is not compatible with the current snapd implementation. As a result I have removed the contents here to avoid further confusion.`

Comment: Damn, this appears to have changed then. Sorry for being inaccurate/out of date.